# error: expected unqualified-id befo re '{' token

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am getting `error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token` in the below code snippet. Can some one clear what went wrong? this is a code snippet from opencv2.1 package.

I am getting this when I build the stasm package using make file from the stasm package.

```
/* Runtime assertion macro */
    #define CV_ASSERT( Condition )                                          \
    {                                                                       \
        if( !(Condition) )                                                  \

            CV_ERROR( CV_StsInternal, "Assertion: " #Condition " failed" ); \
    }
```

Comment: The error needs to be seen in the context of the call to the macro. The compiler will substitute the macro in and then compile. It is in this later stage that you see the error. You can try to run just the preprocessor and see what is really being compiled. Also note that the macro is not good and will fail if used in certain contexts: `if (x) CV_ASSERT(y); else do_something();` will fail to compile for example.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas usually, yes. But in this case, it's a macro followed by 2 invalid lines (because of the stray extra line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra line between:

```
    if( !(Condition) )                                                  \

        CV_ERROR( CV_StsInternal, "Assertion: " #Condition " failed" ); \
```

that shouldn't be there. It should be either

```
    if( !(Condition) )                                                  \
        CV_ERROR( CV_StsInternal, "Assertion: " #Condition " failed" ); \
```

or

```
    if( !(Condition) )                                                  \
                                                                        \
        CV_ERROR( CV_StsInternal, "Assertion: " #Condition " failed" ); \
```